# Can docker use the existing host system to run a command in isolation like lxc-execute

Tags: virtualization, docker, lxc

A lot of the docker examples I have seen involve images of an os, albeit proably a stripped down version.  If you have an existing RHEL system with lxc you can just execute a containerized bash.  Can docker do something similar or do you always need base images that are unrelated to the host OS.

Answer (score 0):

`lxc-execute` does not chroot nor provides a mount namespace, this is why you can start any command with it.

This is currently not possible with Docker, but it should be soon. With the `-o` you will be able to select which namespace you want to use.